# How do I measure correlation between visiting certain specific pages and ultimate conversions?

Tags: google-analytics, conversions, goals

I'm new to using Google Analytics and have to suggest a solution to a problem which I thought would be simple but for which I somehow couldn't find a straightforward solution:
On an ecommerce site, we need to figure out the correlation between visiting different pages (product detail pages for products of a given group) and completing a specific type of conversion (registering for a subscription that gives you free products from that group.) I can't limit the analysis only to customers who land on the product pages – in fact they will mostly come there through a general catalog page.
Is there an elegant way to get precisely this information?

Comment: I think I may have found the simplest and most elegant solution to this: creating a custom segment for those who viewed each of the product pages in that group, then comparing these segments with the All Sessions segment. But if there's an even better solution I'll be glad to hear it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Mike Sapp](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/59771/mike-sapp) found the solution and posted it as a comment:

> I think I may have found the simplest and most elegant solution to this: creating a custom segment for those who viewed each of the product pages in that group, then comparing these segments with the All Sessions segment. But if there's an even better solution I'll be glad to hear it. :)